# Let $a+b+c=3,$ then prove$\sqrt[3]{\frac{a+b}{5ab+4}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{c+b}{5cb+4}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{a+c}{5ac+4}}\ge \sqrt[3]{6}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus, inequality, symmetric-polynomials, uvw

**Problem**

If $a,b,c\ge 0: a+b+c=3,$ then $$\sqrt[3]{\frac{a+b}{5ab+4}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{c+b}{5cb+4}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{a+c}{5ac+4}}\ge \sqrt[3]{6}.\tag{1}$$
I came up with when trying to prove $$\frac{a+b}{5ab+4}+\frac{c+b}{5cb+4}+\frac{a+c}{5ac+4}\ge \frac{2}{3},$$which is not hard by $uvw$ method.
I'm looking for a nice proof $(1).$ It might be useful if the solver give motivate path.

Thank you for helping.

Comment: Where is this problem coming from? Math Olympiad?

Comment: What is uvw method ?

Comment: @Tuong Nguyen Minh See here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h278791 If you know Russian, so I am ready to give a link to my paper about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Some thoughts.**

---

Firstly, we'll prove the following inequality as a lemma.

*Lemma.* For all non-negative real numbers $x,y,z$ satisfying$$x^3y^3+y^3z^3+z^3x^3+\frac{537}{64}(xyz)^3\ge \frac{729}{64},$$then $$x+y+z\ge 3.$$
Equality holds at $(x,y,z)=(1,1,1);\left(0,\dfrac{3}{2},\dfrac{3}{2}\right)$ and permutations.

---

Now, let $$x=\sqrt[3]{\frac{9}{2}}.\sqrt[3]{\frac{a+b}{5ab+4}};y=\sqrt[3]{\frac{9}{2}}.\sqrt[3]{\frac{c+b}{5cb+4}};z=\sqrt[3]{\frac{9}{2}}.\sqrt[3]{\frac{a+c}{5ac+4}}.$$The original problem is rewritten according to $x,y,z$ $$x+y+z\ge 3,$$which the lemma says that it's enough to prove $$\frac{81}{4}\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a+b)(b+c)}{(5ab+4)(5bc+4)}+\frac{391473}{512}\frac{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}{(5ab+4)(5bc+4)(5ca+4)}\ge \frac{729}{64}.$$
From now, we can use $uvw.$

About $uvw,$ see [here.](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h278791)

Answer (score 3):

**Some thought**.

We use the isolated fudging.

It suffices to prove that
$$\sqrt[3]{\frac{a + b}{6(5ab + 4)}}
\ge \frac{55(a^2 + b^2) + 254ab + 385c(a + b)}{110(a^2 + b^2 + c^2) + 1024(ab + bc + ca)}.\tag{1}$$
(*Note*: Taking cyclic sum on (1), we get the desired inequality.)

(1) is true which is verified by *Mathematica*.

Comment: It is nice as usual ! +1

Comment: @TATAbox Thanks.

Comment: I found a proof using CY3 method

Comment: @TATAbox Nice. Is it simple?

Comment: It is calculus proof with contradiction method, uvw. You can see it: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2745991/prove-this-inequality-%ce%a3-cyc-sqrt-fracab3c-ge-frac32-with-abc?noredirect=1

Comment: By the relatives between 3 yields: $x^2y^2+y^2z^2+z^2x^2; (xyz)^2; x+y+z$ we just need to prove a inequality without radicals. The last is the useful uvw.

Comment: @TATAbox It is nice.

Comment: sometimes It helps to attained a proof which we can kill easily by uvw. I am writing it as a demo of this method: Contradiction on three yields.

Comment: @TATAbox It is a common trick.

Comment: yes, contradiction is a common method. For example, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4740147/prove-frac1-sqrt5a4-frac1-sqrt5b4-frac1-sqrt5c4-geq1-f?rq=1
Michael Rozenberg gave a proof by using contradiction method. We can use it in a "immediate" way without contradicting directly to the original condition.

Comment: @TATAbox I mean the method of letting $x = ..., y = ..., z = ...$ and finding the relation among $x, y, z$ in your answer here. I used some times.

Comment: @TATAbox For example, Let $a, b, c > 0$ with $a + b + c = 3$. Prove that
$$\left(\frac{a+1}{a+b} \right)^{\frac25}+\left(\frac{b+1}{b+c} \right)^{\frac25}+\left(\frac{c+1}{c+a} \right)^{\frac25} \ge 3.$$


**Fact 1**: Let $x, y, z \ge 0$ such that $xyz \ge \frac{25}{27}$
and $3xyz - 2(xy + yz + zx) + 2(x + y + z) = 3$. Then
$$x^{2/5} + y^{2/5} + z^{2/5} \ge 3.$$

Let
$$x = \frac{a+1}{a+b}, y = \frac{b+1}{b+c}, z = \frac{c+1}{c+a}.$$
Then
$$xyz \ge \frac{25}{27}$$
and
$$3xyz - 2(xy + yz + zx) + 2(x + y + z) - 3 = 0.$$

By Fact 1, the desired result follows.

Comment: It is nice, indeed. I also use this way to prove Quykhtn's problem (where $2/5$ is replaced $1/2$)

Comment: @TATAbox Nice. In my example, $xyz \ge \frac{25}{27}$ is necessary. It is the interesting point. If we solve the system $x = \frac{a+1}{a+b}, y = \frac{b+1}{b+c}, z = \frac{c+1}{c+a}$, we get $3xyz - 2(xy + yz + zx) + 2(x + y + z) = 3$. However, $x^{2/5} + y^{2/5} + z^{2/5} \ge 3$ is not true without additional constraint $xyz \ge \frac{25}{27}$. In some problems, we don't need this additional constraint.

Comment: I agree. Some problem with equality $(0,t,t)$ is even harder to find.

Comment: For example: Let $a,b,c > 0 : a+b+c=3.$ Prove $$\sqrt{\dfrac{a+1}{a+b}}+\sqrt{\dfrac{b+1}{b+c}}+\sqrt{\dfrac{c+1}{c+a}} \ge 3.$$
Fact: For all $x,y,z>0$ satisfying $$xyz\ge \dfrac{5\sqrt{3}}{9}; x^2+y^2+z^2+\frac{33}{12}xyz\ge \frac{69}{12},$$then $x+y+z\ge 3.$
By denoting $$x=\sqrt{\dfrac{a+1}{a+b}};y=\sqrt{\dfrac{b+1}{b+c}};z=\sqrt{\dfrac{c+1}{c+a}},$$which the Fact gives the desired result.

Comment: @TATAbox Your trick is helpful. Actually, I also think of similar things, but it is not easy to create appropriate form.

Comment: Yes, it makes inequality becomes more interesting!

Comment: @TATAbox Yes, beauty in the inequalities.

Answer (score 2):

A full TATA box's solution.

> Lemma.Let $x$, $y$ and $z$ be non-negative numbers such that:
> $$x^3y^3+x^3y^3+y^3z^3+\frac{537}{64}x^3y^3z^3\geq\frac{729}{64}.$$
> Prove that:
> $$x+y+z\geq3.$$

Let $x+y+z<3,$ $x=kp$, $y=kq$ and $z=kr$, where $k>0$ and $p+q+r=3$.

Thus, $$kp+kq+kr<3=p+q+r,$$ which gives $k<1$ and we obtain:
$$\frac{729}{64}\leq x^3y^3+x^3y^3+y^3z^3+\frac{537}{64}x^3y^3z^3<k^6(p^3q^3+p^3r^3+q^3r^3)+k^9\frac{537}{64}p^3q^3r^3<$$
$$<p^3q^3+p^3r^3+q^3r^3+\frac{537}{64}p^3q^3r^3,$$ which is a contradiction because we'll prove now that:
$$p^3q^3+p^3r^3+q^3r^3+\frac{537}{64}p^3q^3r^3\leq\frac{729}{64}$$ for any non-negatives $p$, $q$ and $r$ such that $p+q+r=3$.

Indeed, let $p+q+r=3u$, $pw+pr+qr=3v^2$ and $pqr=w^3$.

Thus, $u=1$ and we need to prove that:
$$27v^6-27uv^2w^3+3w^6+\frac{537}{64}w^9\leq\frac{729}{64}$$ or $f(w^3)\geq0,$ where
$$f(w^3)=243u^9-179w^9-u^3(9v^6-9uv^2w^3+w^6).$$
Easy to see that $f$ is a concave function.  But the concave function gets a minimal value for an extremal value of $w^3$,which by $uvw$ (https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h278791) happens in the following cases.

1. $w^3=0$.

Let $r=0$.

Thus, by AM-GM  $$p^3q^3+p^3r^3+q^3r^3+\frac{537}{64}p^3q^3r^3=p^3q^3\leq\left(\frac{p+q}{2}\right)^6=\frac{729}{64}.$$

2. Two variables are equal.

Let $q=p$ and $r=3-2p$, where $0\leq p\leq\frac{3}{2}.$

Thus, it remains to prove that:
$$p^6+2p^3(3-2p)^3+\frac{537}{64}p^6(3-2p)^3\leq\frac{729}{64}$$ or
$$(p-1)^2(3-2p)(81+216p+387p^2+198p^3+537p^4+716p^5-716p^6)\geq0,$$ which is true for $0\leq p\leq \frac{3}{2}.$

Id est, by using lemma, it's enough to prove that:
$$128\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a+b)(a+c)}{(5ab+4)(5ac+4)}+4833\prod_{cyc}\frac{a+b}{5ab+4}\geq72.$$
Now, let $a+b+c=3u$, $ab+ac+bc=3v^2$ and $abc=w^3$.

Thus, we need to prove that
$$128\sum_{cyc}(a+b)(a+c)(5bc+4)+4833\prod_{cyc}(a+b)\geq72\prod_{cyc}(5ab+4)$$ and we see again that we need to prove $g(w^3)\geq0,$ where $g$ is a concave function(the LHS is a linear of $w^3$ and a coefficient before $w^6$ in the RHS is equal to $72\cdot5^3>0$.

Thus, it's enough to check two following cases.

1. $c=0$.

We need to prove here $$128(3a\cdot4+3b\cdot4+ab(5ab+4))+4833\cdot3ab\geq72\cdot4\cdot4(5ab+4)$$ or
$$128ab(5ab+4)+4833\cdot3ab\geq72\cdot4\cdot4\cdot5ab,$$ which is obvious.

2. $b=a$ and $c=3-2a,$ where $0\leq a\leq1.5$.

Here we obtain:
$$(a-1)^2a(9251+5460a+6000a^2-6000a^3)\geq0,$$ which is true for $0\leq a\leq1.5$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\;f(x,y)=\sqrt[\Large 3]{\dfrac{x+y}{4+5x y}},\;$ then
$$F(a, b, c)=f(a,b)+f(b,c)+f(c,a),$$
$$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\,f(x,y) =\dfrac13 \dfrac{}{}\sqrt[\Large3]{\dfrac{5xy+4}{x+y}}^2\, \dfrac{4+5xy-5y(x+y)}{(4+5xy)^2}
=\dfrac13\dfrac{4-5y^2}{\sqrt[\Large 3\,]{(4+5xy)^4(x+y)^2}\mathstrut}
=g(x,y),$$
$$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}\,f(x,y) = g(y,x),$$

$\color{brown}{\textbf{The inner stationary points.}}$

The inner stationary points can be found from the system
$$\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial a}\,(F(a,b,c)+\lambda(3-a-b-c))=g(a,b)+g(a,c)-\lambda=0\\[4pt]
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial b}\,(F(a,b,c)+\lambda(3-a-b-c))=g(b,a)+g(b,c)-\lambda=0\\[4pt]
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial c}\,(F(a,b,c)+\lambda(3-a-b-c))=g(c,b)+g(c,a)-\lambda=0\\[4pt]
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \lambda}\,(F(a,b,c)+\lambda(3-a-b-c))=3-a-b-c=0.
\end{cases}$$
or
$$\begin{cases}
\dfrac{4-5b^2}{\sqrt[\Large 3\,]{(4+5ab)^4(a+b)^2}\mathstrut}
+\dfrac{4-5c^2}{\sqrt[\Large 3\,]{(4+5ca)^4(c+a)^2}\mathstrut}=\lambda\\[4pt]
\dfrac{4-5a^2}{\sqrt[\Large 3\,]{(4+5ab)^4(a+b)^2}\mathstrut}
+\dfrac{4-5c^2}{\sqrt[\Large 3\,]{(4+5bc)^4(b+c)^2}\mathstrut}=\lambda\\[4pt]
\dfrac{4-5b^2}{\sqrt[\Large 3\,]{(4+5bc)^4(b+c)^2}\mathstrut}
+\dfrac{4-5a^2}{\sqrt[\Large 3\,]{(4+5ca)^4(c+a)^2}\mathstrut}=\lambda\\[4pt]
a+b+c=3
\end{cases}$$

After eliminating of $\lambda$ we get the overdefined system

$$\begin{cases}
\dfrac{5(a^2-b^2)}{\sqrt[\Large 3\,]{(4+5ab)^4(a+b)^2}\mathstrut}
+(4-5c^2)\left(\dfrac1{\sqrt[\Large 3\,]{(4+5ca)^4(c+a)^2}\mathstrut}
-\dfrac1{\sqrt[\Large 3\,]{(4+5bc)^4(b+c)^2}\mathstrut}\right)=0\\[4pt]
\dfrac{5(b^2-c^2)}{\sqrt[\Large 3\,]{(4+5bc)^4(b+c)^2}\mathstrut}
+(4-5a^2)\left(\dfrac1{\sqrt[\Large 3\,]{(4+5ab)^4(a+b)^2}\mathstrut}
-\dfrac1{\sqrt[\Large 3\,]{(4+5ca)^4(c+a)^2}\mathstrut}\right)=0\\[4pt]
\dfrac{5(c^2-a^2)}{\sqrt[\Large 3\,]{(4+5ca)^4(c+a)^2}\mathstrut}
+(4-5b^2)\left(\dfrac1{\sqrt[\Large 3\,]{(4+5bc)^4(b+c)^2}\mathstrut}
-\dfrac1{\sqrt[\Large 3\,]{(4+5ab)^4(a+b)^2}\mathstrut}\right)=0\\[4pt]
a+b+c=3,
\end{cases}$$

If $\;a>b>c>0,\;$ then

- $\;(4+5ca)^4(c+a)^2 > (4+5bc)^4(b+c)^2\;$ and $\;4-5c^2>0.$
- $\;(4+5ab)^4(a+b)^2 > (4+5ca)^4(c+a)^2\;$ and $\;4-5a^2>0.$
- $\;(4+5ab)^4(a+b)^2 > (4+5ca)^4(c+a)^2\;$ and $\;4-5b^2>0.$

If $\;0<a<b<c,\;$ then

- $\;(4+5ca)^4(c+a)^2 < (4+5bc)^4(b+c)^2\;$ and $\;4-5c^2>0.$
- $\;(4+5ab)^4(a+b)^2 < (4+5ca)^4(c+a)^2\;$ and $\;4-5a^2>0.$
- $\;(4+5ab)^4(a+b)^2 < (4+5ca)^4(c+a)^2\;$ and $\;4-5b^2>0.$

Both of the variants mean that $\;a<1,b<1,c<1,\;$ i.e. $a+b+c<3,$ in contradiction with the last equation of the system.

If WLOG $\;a=b,\;$ then
$$\begin{cases}
\dfrac{5(a^2-c^2)}{\sqrt[\Large 3\,]{(4+5ac)^4(a+c)^2}\mathstrut}
+(4-5a^2)\left(\dfrac1{\sqrt[\Large 3\,]{(4+5a^2)^4(2a)^2}\mathstrut}
-\dfrac1{\sqrt[\Large 3\,]{(4+5ca)^4(c+a)^2}\mathstrut}\right)=0\\[4pt]
\dfrac{5(c^2-a^2)}{\sqrt[\Large 3\,]{(4+5ca)^4(c+a)^2}\mathstrut}
+(4-5a^2)\left(\dfrac1{\sqrt[\Large 3\,]{(4+5ac)^4(a+c)^2}\mathstrut}
-\dfrac1{\sqrt[\Large 3\,]{(4+5a^2)^4(2a)^2}\mathstrut}\right)=0\\[4pt]
2a+c=3,
\end{cases}$$

$$\begin{cases}
\dfrac{10a^2-5c^2-4}{\sqrt[\Large 3\,]{(4+5ac)^4(a+c)^2}\mathstrut}
+\dfrac{4-5a^2}{\sqrt[\Large 3\,]{(4+5a^2)^4(2a)^2}\mathstrut}=0\\[4pt]
2a+c=3,
\end{cases}$$

$$(10a^2-5c^2-4)^3(4+5a^2)^4(2a)^2=(5a^2-4)^3(4+5ac)^4(a+c)^2,$$
$$(10a^2-5(3-2a)^2-4)^3(4+5a^2)^4(2a)^2=(5a^2-4)^3(4+5a(3-2a))^4(3-a)^2,$$
$$(-10a^2+60a-49)^3(4+5a^2)^4(2a)^2=(5a^2-4)^3(-10a^2+15a+4)^4(3-a)^2,$$
with the roots in $(0,3)$
$$\dbinom{a}{F(a,a,3-2a)}\in\left\{\approx\dbinom{0.05342847}{2.00156},\dbinom{1}{\sqrt[\Large3]6}\right\}.$$

Therefore, the least inner value of $F$ is $\sqrt[\Large 3]6.$

$\color{brown}{\textbf{The edges.}}$

Since
$$\;F(3,0,0)=2\,\sqrt[\Large3]{\dfrac34}=\sqrt[\Large3]6$$
and
$$\;F\left(\dfrac32,\dfrac32,0\right)=\sqrt[\Large3\,]{\dfrac3{4+\dfrac{45}4}}
+2\sqrt[\Large3]{\dfrac38}=\sqrt[\Large3]{\dfrac{12}{61}}+\sqrt[\Large3]3 >\sqrt[\Large3]6,$$
then
$$\color{green}{\mathbf{F(a,b,c)\ge \sqrt[\Large3]6}}$$
at the task constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Calling $f(a,b) = \sqrt[3]{\frac{a+b}{5ab+4}}$ and $F(a,b,c) = f(a,b)+f(b,c)+f(c,a)$ we have

$$
\cases{
f(a,b)\le F(a,b,c)\\
f(b,c)\le F(a,b,c)\\
f(c,a)\le F(a,b,c)
}
$$

so the minimum will be found amongst the problems

$$
\cases{
\min_{a,b}F(a,b,0),\ \text{s.t.}\ \ a+b=3,a \ge 0,b\ge 0\\
\min_{b,c}F(0,b,c),\ \text{s.t.}\ \ b+c=3,b \ge 0,c\ge 0\\
\min_{a,c}F(a,0,c),\ \text{s.t.}\ \ a+c=3,a \ge 0,c\ge 0\\
}
$$

as the problem has nice symmetry we can follow with

$$
\min_{a,b}\sqrt[3]{\frac{a+b}{5ab+4}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{b}{4}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{a}{4}}\ \ \text{s.t.}\ \ \ a+b=3, a\ge 0, b\ge 0
$$

or

$$
\min_a\sqrt[3]{\frac{3}{5a(3-a)+4}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{3-a}{4}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{a}{4}}\ \ \text{s.t.}\ \ a \ge 0
$$

We have solutions at

$$
\cases{
a = 3, b = c = 0\\
a = 0, b = 3, c= 0\\
a = 0, b= 0, c=3\\
a = b = c = 1\\
}
$$

with value $\sqrt[3]{6}$. The last solution cannot be detected by this procedure.